# Newton first law of motion, braking suddenly in car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

While driving down the road,  if you hit the brakes suddenly, your body moves forward. Explain the reason for this.

Comment: Hi user1530249 - it helps if you ask your question as a question, not as a statement. Also, this is explained on many websites about motion. What other explanations did you look at, and what did you have trouble understanding about them?

Answer (score 2):

While you're driving a car, you share a reference frame with it, meaning your velocities and accelerations are approximately equal. When you hit the breaks, you no longer share a frame of reference as the car is decelerating with respect to the road. However you're still moving forward until acted on by an external force, i.e. your seatbelt.

Answer (score 1):

"if you hit the brakes suddenly, your body moves forward"

It was always moving forward. That's what cars are for.

Let's say you're walking down the street with your friend, and they stop and you don't. What does that look like?